# How to remove special characters like "$" from an expression using regix

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression to remove "$" from my expression.
I actually want a search regix that can fetch me all the user that does not contains $ in their name for eg:

```
12134$
22323$
12132
23232$
22333
```

the result that the regix can provide me with is by fetching all the users that does not have "$" in them
result from the above list will be

```
12132
22333
```

Comment: I have tried using '^((?!$).)*$', but was unsuccessful fetching the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negated character classes match any character not in it:

```
^[^$]+$
```

would match all complete lines consisting of only characters other than `$`

You can try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/d3S1cq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\$).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dKdCIX/1/).

---

E.g. in `JavaScript` this could be:

```js
let strings = ['12134$', '22323$', '12132', '23232$', '22333'];
rx = /^(?!.*\$).+/

let users = strings.filter(item => {
    return item.match(rx);
});

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind at the end of the string:

```
^.*(?<!\$)$
```

This will find all users that don't have a $ at the end. (The 2nd $ is an anchor in this regex)